# ASP.NET gives multiple control ID error for one control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a control to a placeholder dynamically, like this:

```
int fileCount = Convert.ToInt32(lblCount.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i<fileCount ; i++)
    {
        FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
        if(PlaceHolder1.HasControls())
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.AddAt(i,fu);
        else
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(fu);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls[i].ID = "123456abcdef" + i;
    }
```

But I get the error

> Multiple controls with the same ID '123456abcdef0' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Why? Only one control should get that ID on each iteration of the loop.

EDIT: Should mention that I haven't actually been able to test the loop, I get the error even when fileCount is 1.

SOLUTION: I called this function from a "foreach" loop in page load when I thought it was outside of it. Still, having the clear() method in mind will remove the necessity of the addat part of the function.

Comment: Are you sure this code doesn't run twice?

Comment: please provide more code - method call?  entire method?

Comment: Why are you using `Controls.AddAt` if you add the control at the end anyway? That's at least confusing.

Comment: You should provide your entire code for this page. The loop as provided works as expected.

Comment: Have you tried to set the ID before you add the control to the placeholder?

Comment: The function right now is only called from the page load. Could the page load have been called more than once somehow?

Comment: D'oh! This function WAS being called more than once. I put it in a foreach loop when I didn't mean to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a clear before you start adding:

```
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();
```

And your add statements can be simplified as follows:

```
FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
fu.Id = "123456abcdef" + i;
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(fu);
```

Comment: Well, if this is the answer, then you should double check your code. It means that the section you posted is called twice or more, hence the need to clear it at each iteration. You should only fill the placeholder at postback (or callback) and to really make sure it's filled once.

Comment: This worked! I don't know how I missed the clear method, which helps in more ways than one. (I was using the addAt method before because I thought I would have to overwrite controls).

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, you can try something like below.

```
int fileCount = Convert.ToInt32(lblCount.Text); 
for (int i = 0; i<fileCount ; i++)     
{         
     FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
     fu.ID =  "123456abcdef" + i;
     PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(fu); 
}
```

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Change to this:

```
 int fileCount = Convert.ToInt32(lblCount.Text);
    for (int i = 0; i<fileCount ; i++)
    {
        FileUpload fu = new FileUpload();
        fu.ID = string.Format("fu_{0}", i);
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(fu);
    }
```